# NSFetchedResultsController with privateQueueConcurrencyType - changes do not call delegate methods

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm unable to get my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods called when setting the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` up with a `concurrencyType` value of `privateQueueConcurrencyType`.

Consider this example:

```
fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Note> = {
    // Initialize Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Note> = Note.fetchRequest()

    // Add Sort Descriptors
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "updatedAt", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.coreDataManager.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    // Configure Fetched Results Controller
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

Where the `coreDataManager` class has this:

```
private(set) lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)

    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator

    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

If I call `fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.delete(note)` and then save, the `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath` method is called and I can respond to the deletion of the note object.

If I change the code above to be:

```
fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Note> = {
    // Initialize Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Note> = Note.fetchRequest()

    // Add Sort Descriptors
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "updatedAt", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .concurrencyType`)

    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.coreDataManager.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator

    // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    // Configure Fetched Results Controller
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

Which specifically changes the managed object context 'usage' from using `self.coreDataManager.managedObjectContext` to a new version that should work on a background thread, the delegate methods are never called when items are deleted.

- I fetch once in `viewDidLoad`
- This works fine when using the 'main' managed object, `self.coreDataController.managedObjectContext`
- I am more or less using the code available at https://github.com/bartjacobs/ExploringTheFetchedResultsControllerDelegateProtocol to demonstrate this - as I stated above please adjust the `fetchedResultsController` method to use a different `NSManagedObjectContext`

So my main question is - how do I get the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods to be called when using this type of `NSManagedObjectContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fetchedResultsController` is monitoring the context that you just created and that context is not processing updates.  If you want this context to change you have to set `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true` for the context.

Comment: I will investigate this, thanks for the tip.  I see that is is only available on iOS 10+ and for the time being we still need to support 9.3+ - but this is a good start at least!

Comment: In general, it is VERY rare to need to have a fetchedResultsController attached to any context other than the main context (ie viewContext).  If you want a context to update with changes pre iOS 9 you can register for the change notification and do the merges yourself.

Comment: @JonRose rare to have nsfetchresultcontroller on a different queue than the main thread? How laggy will any app be if every fetch is called on the main thread?! >:(

Comment: generally you need to fetch to display information to the user, so I don't see how you can gain very much by doing the fetch in the background and then passing it to the main thread.  9 out of 10 times that I have seen people try to fetch on a background thread they had very bad inefficient queries.

Answer (score 0):

As John told NSFetchedResultsController is monitoring only associated managed context like

```js
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> in
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>.init(entityName: "Repository")
        let descriptors = [NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "name", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "name", ascending: true)]
        request.sortDescriptors = descriptors
        let resultsController = NSFetchedResultsController.init(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: CoreDataManager.shared.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        
        resultsController.delegate = self
        return resultsController
    }()
```

Inherit your **.mainQueueConcurrencyType** from **.privateQueueConcurrencyType** like below code

```js
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext.init(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.parent = self.privateQueueManagedObjectContext
        context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        return context
    }()
    
    lazy var privateQueueManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext.init(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        return context
    }()
```

Dont forget to add         **context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true** in your maincontext to notify background operations on privateQue context.

I hope this will work